Effective nuclear charge increases along period despite increasing number of electrons
I learned that when an increasing number of electrons are present in the orbitals, then nuclear force decreases as it needs to hold more electrons.
Given this, why does the effective nuclear charge increase along the period?

As you go across the periodic table, you'll experience two things:

An additional proton
An additional electron

While the number of electrons increases, these electrons are added to the same principal energy level. Because they're in the same shell, they don't add a significant amount of shielding from the nucleus. For all intents and purposes, we'll consider that shielding relatively constant.
The additional proton, without much change in shielding, will cause the electrons to feel a stronger pull from the nucleus. This results in the increase in effective nuclear charge that you're seeing.
